# Event Viewer sorting data

Tags: asp.net, events, event-viewer

How can I filter the Event viewer by databinding it in a gridview?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the event viewer by storing the data from the event view local in the datatable and then apply the filter the depending on your requirement, before binding to the grid view control.

hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop throgh all entries and check whether each entry matches your condition. If yes, then add it to data table as a new row, and finally bind this datatable to your grid.